# Unity - Random generation from prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

I'm trying to make random generation similar to a game called Spooky's Jumpscare Mansion in Unity but I have no idea how to do that. I want to make a script that randomly selects from a list of rooms and then inserts it into the game and then when you open the door to the previous room the screen will fade and then you will be in the next room. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can treat ever room as a separate scene. When you interact with a door you can play your fade to black animation, load a random scene and play a fade from black animation.